# What will happen if I perimeter bond vinyl flooring against manufacturer recommendation?

Tags: vinyl-flooring

I'm installing sheet vinyl in my kitchen. I read the installation manual. I can do either full spread or loose lay.

I'm planning on using adhesive tape, but the installation manual says "DO NOT PERIMETER BOND FLOOR".

My question is why can't I perimeter bond the floor with tape?  What will happen if I do?

Answer (score 2):

I believe the issue is that the center of the flooring material can expand and if the entire perimeter is bonded, the center will wave or wrinkle.  When the entire floor is bonded, and expansion and contraction happens on a smaller scale.

That said, I have never installed sheet vinyl and I don't know what the right solution is.

Comment: It's not so much about expansion, but movement in general. Loose-laid floors tend to shift around a bit over time.

Answer (score 2):

This one is easy, if you perimeter bond the flooring ... When the sun shines in the room, the middle of the flooring will buckle up, enough a sliding chair might mar it or even create a tripping hazard :(   Seriously the instructions should tell you why, not just give orders.

Comment: It is a classic problem: If the instructions give the reasons then some people will say "that won't happen to me" and then go against the instructions. If the instructions don't give the reasons then some people will say "doesn't make sense, so I'm not going to bother" and then go against the instructions. Damned if you do, damned if you don't.